# Errors when installing basemaplib

Tags: python-3.x, macos, matplotlib-basemap

I am having issues when installing basemap on my Macbook using python3 setup.py install,

> src/_proj.c:6801:13: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
>       tstate->exc_traceback = tb;
>               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
>               curexc_traceback
>   /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:238:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
>       PyObject *curexc_traceback;
>                 ^
>   52 warnings and 15 errors generated.
>   error: Command "clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Isrc -I/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c src/_proj.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/src/_proj.o -MMD -MF build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/src/_proj.o.d" failed with exit status 1

what could be causing this?

Comment: Did you download basemap and try to install it manually? If so, have you considered using a package manager like `macports` or `homebrew`? I personally use `macports` and haven't had any problems installing python related packages. Sometimes I need to resort to `pip`, but that's as difficult as it can get ...

Comment: It is complicated to install basemap. I suggest you use [conda](https://conda.io/docs/). With conda:  `conda install -c anaconda basemap`

Comment: I believe that the problem is python3.7. Try with python3.6

Comment: Sounds like a version mismatch in dependencies along the way. It would be much easier to read the error if it were formatted as code. That would preserve the lines instead of mashing everything into a homogenous mess.

Comment: Going off of Lucas's comment - I found installing basemap using Canopy is the easiest way. Not a plug for them, but Canopy has a built-in "package manager", which you can install packages at the click of the button. The caveat however, is that you're restricted to using the Canopy developing environment rather than say, a text editor such as Sublime Text.

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I get the same error, and I think the solution is to regenerate the C sources (see https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/414), but I haven't actually found out how to do that...